# Using PHP to change the information displayed inside a label

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have the following code that is supposed to be a list of "facilities" and I made a div acting as a popUp that contain information that should change depending on the Lab I click info, I already made the popUp appear and dissapear playing with adding a hide and show class to it using Js.

But I don´t really know how should I write that each li element has to retrive information from a database I made in wamp for practice purposes, should I use a label? Or perhaps create a table instead of a list?

In short I need that when I click Lab 1 the popUp says Name: Lab1, if the clicks Lab 2, then Lab2 and so on. The code I was going to use in PHP is below as well.

HTML

```
<div class="box">
          <p>Lab #1</p>
          <p class="info"><a href="#" id="lnkInfo">Info</p></a>
          <p class="info"><a href="reservarLab.html">Reservar</p></a>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
          <p>Lab #2</p>
          <p class="info"><a href="#">Info</p></a>
          <p class="info"><a href="reservarLab.html">Reservar</p></a>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
          <p>Lab #3</p>
          <p class="info"><a href="#">Info</p></a>
          <p class="info"><a href="reservarLab.html">Reservar</p></a>
      </div>


    <div class="popUp1 hide" id="popUpCorrecto1">
        <div class="estiloPopUp">
          <span>Información de laboratorio</span>
          <span value="Cerrar" id="btnCerrar">x</span>
        </div>
           <ul>
          <li>Nombre: Lab #1</li>
          <li>Carrera: Desarrollo</li>
          <li>Capacidad: 20</li>
          <li>Ubicación:Abajo</li>
          <li><a href='horarios.html'>Ver horarios</a></li>
        </ul>

          <input type = "button" value = "Eliminar" id = "btnEliminar" onclick="window.location='labEliminado.html';" />
          <input type = "button" value = "Modificar" id = "btnModificar"  onclick="window.location='modificarLab.html';" />

        </div>
```

PHP

```
 function displayLab(){
$query = "SELECT bk.idLab , bk.capacidad, bk.carrera, bk.ubicacion FROM labs";

$result = do_query($query);

 return $result;
 }

 function displayBooks(){

$books = getBooks();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($books)){
echo '<tr>' .
        '<td>' . $row['idLab'] . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $row['carrera'] . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $row['capacidad'] . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $row['ubicación'] . '</td>' .
     '</tr>';
}
 }
```

Gonna add the box CSS just in case:

```
  .box {
  color: #ecf0f1;
  background-color: #34495e;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 75px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 3px;
}


.box:hover{
  border:2px solid white;
}
```

JS for PopUp

```
var elementoVerInfo = document.getElementById('lnkInfo'),
elementoBotonCerrar = document.getElementById('btnCerrar'); 

elementoVerInfo.addEventListener('click', function () {
displayPopUp('popUpCorrecto1');
 });

elementoBotonCerrar.addEventListener('click', function () {
hidePopUp('popUpCorrecto1');
});

function displayPopUp(pIdDivToShow){
var fElementDivToShow = document.getElementById(pIdDivToShow),
newClass ='';
newClass = fElementDivToShow.className.replace('hide','');
fElementDivToShow.className = newClass + ' show';
}

function hidePopUp(pIdDivToShow){
 var fElementDivToShow = document.getElementById(pIdDivToShow),
 newClass ='';
 newClass = fElementDivToShow.className.replace('show','');
 fElementDivToShow.className = newClass + ' hide';
}
```

That is if I decide to use a table...and if the code runs >.>

Anyway thanks a lot in advance
Best Wishes

Comment: This is easiest done in JS, can we see your code that shows the popup?

Comment: You should use JS, and there are different approaches, ajax or using data attributes, also, you should use js library like jquery.

Comment: Do you know where could I find something akin to what I am looking for  so I can use as reference? I have never ever tried this before so I cannot make head or tails out of it >.<

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else wants to do something similar I came with a solution:

```
function displayLabs(){

$labs = getLabs();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($labs)){
echo '<ul>' .
        '<li>"Nombre: "'. $row['idlab'] . '</li>' .
        '<li>"Capacidad: "'. $row['capacidad'] . '</li' .
        '<li>"Carrera: "'. $row['carrera'] . '</li>' .
        '<li>"Ubicación: "'. $row['ubicacion'] . '</li>' .
     '</ul>';
   }
}
```